# How to test the android purchase mechanism?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am new to android. I am trying to add in-app billing goods to my app nad I would like to test the purchase mechanism while publishing the alpha version of the apk file.
I followed the instruction in the developers guide but when I go to the "In-app..." section I am asked to upload a new apk file and to register for a commerce account.
Can someone tell me how to test my app with fake purchases?

Answer (score 0):

if you have not found any answer.

If the **Developer Console** is asking you to upload a new APK file, that is because you need to add the billing permission to your app to be able to set in-app items.

add the following permission to your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

of course you will need to add internet permissions as well.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

once you add this permissions you can go to **Developer Console** in your app APK section and click on **Beta Testing** tab and upload your new APK.

After that you will need to add beta testers email to test your app, the beta testers accounts will be able to download the app once its available and buy your items as test with no real charges.

Now you can go to in-app section and add your in-app items.
you can add manual managed items and subscription items.

I hope this can help.